# Unresolved featured questions (bounty): How about creating an extra tab and award for important unresolved problems?

Tags: feature-request, badges, bounty, unanswered-questions, badge-request

**Problem description**

Have you ever offered a bounty on a question for a difficult or important problem and still nobody answered after seven days? Maybe you even got lots of upvotes, but nobody had a solution?

There are a lot of questions regarding difficult problems which are never resolved, even though *somebody put a bounty* on them and *they were upvoted* a lot. Solving those questions even if they are a bit older might be useful not only for the questionare, but also for certain visitors in the future.

**Current state**

Currently we have an "unresolved" tab for certain tags: 
[image]

After clicking it we have the following view:

[image]

**Solution approach**

My suggestion is to motivate users and experts to answer highly upvoted and/or unresolved (previous) bounty questions by the following measures:

- Introduce a tab at the "Unanswered Questions" page for featured questions with no accepted answer and allow the bounty to be awarded even after the 7 days have passed and order them by upvotes
- Introduce a new badge (gold or silver) for answering old questions with having a bounty or which were highly upvoted or both (a bit similar to the Necromancer badge)

Comment: 'Someone put a bounty on it' is only an indicator that someone was willing to pay some reputation to draw attention to a post. If you need more attention for a post, *put another bounty on it*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The idea is not to constantly put a question in the "featured" section, but to make really hard problems more likely to be solved.

Comment: And how do you make hard problems more likely to be solved, other than drawing more attention to it with a bounty?

Comment: @Cerbrus Hmm I think I have stated quite clearly what I suggest and why. What is the point in putting 20 bounties on the same problem if it is simply only to be solved by very few people and maybe in a large timeframe?

Comment: If a bounty expires, it expires. It's gone. Your suggestion removes the point of having bounties expire... The point is that you "pay" for the extra visibility the question gets.

Comment: @Cerbrus It understand very well what a bounty is. But if a question is upvoted a lot and never answered despite having a bounty it indicates the following: "Important problem, but hard to solve". And it would be nice to motivate the community further to solve those questions as it also improves the value of Stackoverflow!

Comment: @Blackbam: And you do that by adding another bounty...

Comment: @Cerbrus: Sure this is a legit answer. My idea was to improve motviation for this additionally. However I accept if the community agrees that this is not necessary ‍♂️

Comment: @Blackbam: a problem that is hard to solve is not going to get solved any better with a separate section. Putting another bounty on it is going to give it much more attention, because the 'upvoted and once had a bounty on it' section is going to be very crowded anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a major unsolved question, then more exposure won't help with it. In all likelihood the person who finally answers it will have either found it through the Unanswered tab, or found it years ago and only now figured out a solution.

Even then, it might *never* get resolved. For example, take a look through the [bounties with no deadline](//codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5243/62402) over on PPCG: about half of them are 6+ months old and still unresolved. If you want it answered, then a much better idea might be to give it to some CS grad students to figure out.